# implement queue with linked list

Tags: c++, queue

I wrote the code for implementing queue with linked list, but has some bug that I cannot figure out. When I first push an item into the queue, it works find, but when I tried to push the second one, it gives me runtime error. Could you please help me with it? Thank you very much!
The following is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
struct Node{
    T data;
    Node* next;
    Node(T d, Node* n=NULL): data(d), next(n){}
};


template<typename T>
class myqueue{
    private:
        Node<T> * first;
        Node<T> * last;
    public:
        myqueue(){}
        void push(T da){
            if(first==NULL) {
                first=new Node<T>(da);
                last=first;
            }
            else {

                last->next=new Node<T>(da);
                last=last->next;

                }
        }   
        void pop(){
          if(last!=NULL){
            Node<T> * temp=first;
            first=first->next;
            delete temp;
          }
        }
        void front(){
           if(first!=NULL) cout<< first->data;
        }
        bool isempty(){
            return last==NULL;
        }
};

int main(){
    myqueue<int> q;
    q.push(1);
    q.push(2);
    q.front();
    /*
    q.push(3);
    q.push(4);
    q.push(5);
    cout<<q.front();
    */

}


compile error: runtime error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `first` and `last` pointers are uninitialized, so you have undefined behaviour. Initialize them with a member initialization list:

```
myqueue::myqueue() : first(NULL), last(NULL) {}
```

Comment: Is that I should always initialize a pointer?

Comment: @dianedan You should never use the value of an uninitialized variable. This is one way of initializing pointers that are members. Alternatively, you could have assigned `NULL` to them in the constructor (`first = NULL; last = NULL;`).

Comment: I have another question regarding the pointer. In this case, I think first and last store the address of an object/type. Why I can use first==NULL but not *first==NULL for comparsion?

Comment: @dianedan `first` is a pointer. You can compare a pointer to `NULL`, as in `first == NULL`. It says "Is the first pointer NULL?" However, `*first` *dereferences* the pointer to give you the `Node<T>` object it points at. You can't compare a `Node<T>` object to NULL, as in `*first == NULL`.

Comment: I have this question because I encounter this kind of problem before, when I add the deference operator before the pointer variable and compare with NULL it works, but that pointer is different type not Node I defined here.

Comment: @dianedan That's because `NULL` is actually a very silly thing. It is really just the literal `0` and is not of pointer type at all. So if you have a pointer `p` that points at an `int`, you can then do `*p == NULL` because you *can* compare an `int` with `NULL`. In fact, this is so silly that C++11 (the latest version of C++) has introduced a new keyword `nullptr` to use instead of `NULL`. You *cannot* do `*p == nullptr`.

Comment: void reverse(char* s){
    if(s==NULL) return;  
 char* start=s;
 char* end=s;
 while(*end){   //not while(end) !!!
  end++;
 }
 end--;
 char temp; 
 while(start<end){
  temp=*start;
  *start=*end;
  *end=temp;
  start++;
  end--;
    }
}

Comment: that is the example, I encountered, when doing while loop check whether end is NULL, it should add deference operator. I would like to know why?

Comment: @dianedan This is completely different. This is to do with the fact that C-style strings are null-terminated. This is not the same as a null pointer. It means that strings have a character at the end with value 0 - the null character (not the same as a null pointer). So what you're checking with `*end`, is whether the character pointed to by `end` is the null character.

Comment: OH! That's the reason! I got you! Thank you very much! I think I didn't have a clear understanding between NULL pointer and NULL char before you pointed it out! Thank you! It is very helpful!!